# Получить записи из группы Facebook

Tags: php, facebook-api

Хочу получить новые или (если проще) все записи из группы фейсбука. Создателям группы являюсь я.

Возможно ли это реализовать через https://github.com/facebook/php-graph-sdk ?

Может есть какие-то примеры для быстрого старта?

В идеале хотелось бы чтобы при добавлении поста в группу чтобы приходил вебхук с данными поста на мой URL. видел там есть webhook, но не уверен рассчитан ли он на такое)

Буду благодарен за информацию.

Comment: На вашем месте, я бы хотя бы плюс ответу поставил. Если он помог.

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете получить всю информацию о странице в формате JSON. Дальше вы можете распарсить её и так вы получите все записи вашей группы. Потом вы можете регулярно посылать запрос, забирать данные в JSON и проверять изменились ли они. Если да, то посылаете себе.

Чтобы получить данные, то сначала зайдите на [эту страницу](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/) и получите токен под названием `Page Access Token`. Затем введите такой URL:

`https://graph.facebook.com/v2.0/{ID группы}/feed?access_token={Токен, который вы получили}&limit=250`

Если у вас нет ошибки и выводится JSON файл, то идем дальше.

Вы можете получить этот файл вот так:

```
    $data = file_get_contents('
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.0/{ID группы}/feed?access_token={Токен,который вы получили}&limit=250
');
```

Затем парсите файл и выводите все записи. Ну и если нужно при добавлении записи уведомлять, то как я сказал выше, регулярно получаете данные и проверяете.

Comment: А как получить токен? Куда заходить?

Comment: @iKey Ох, я извиняюсь, я совсем забыл ссылку добавить.

Comment: Я обязательно проверю и отпишусь, просто не было времени. И если ответ помог, отмечу его галочкой и обязательно поставлю +. Спасибо вам большое за то что уделили время!)